# Difficulty with: If $P,Q \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ and $0 \leq P \leq Q \implies ||P|| \leq ||Q||$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

In the book "Observation and Control for Operator Semigroups" of Marius Tucsnak and George Weiss page 392. I found the following statement

If $P,Q \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ and $0 \leq P \leq Q \implies ||P|| \leq ||Q|| \quad (*) $

Which they said that we can get it easily using this one:  If $P \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ and $P \geqslant 0$ then  $$|\langle P x, y\rangle|^{2} \leqslant\langle P x, x\rangle \cdot\langle P y, y\rangle \quad \forall x, y \in H   (**)$$
as you can see in the attached picture: [image: 1]
While thinking about this I thought that $(*)$ is obvious and we don't need any other statement (!) which seems to be not the case here.

I would like to ask for any hint or insight to get $(*)$ from $(**)$, and I would like also to see some example on where $(*)$ fail to be satisfied.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=Px$ in the inequality $|\langle Px,y\rangle|^2 \le \langle Px,x\rangle\langle Py,y\rangle$:
$$
        \|Px\|^4 \le \langle Px,x\rangle\langle PPx,Px\rangle \le \langle Px,x\rangle\|P^2x\|\|Px\| \le \langle Px,x\rangle\|P\|\|Px\|^2 \\
              \|Px\|^2 \le \|P\|\langle Px,x\rangle \\
            \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Px\|^2 \le \|P\|\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Px,x\rangle \\
                 \|P\|^2\le \|P\|\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Px,x\rangle \\
                 \|P\| \le \sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Px,x\rangle
$$
The opposite inequality follows from $\langle Px,x\rangle \le \|Px\|\|x\|$. Therefore,
$$
                         \|P\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Px,x\rangle.
$$
That gives you what you want, starting with $0 \le P\le Q$. For $\|x\|=1$,
$$
                      0 \le \langle Px,x\rangle \le \langle Qx,x\rangle \le \|Q\| \\
           \|P\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Px,x\rangle \le \|Q\|.
$$